# Is there a deadline as to when is Google Analytics reporting API v3 or v4 deprecating?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics reporting API v3 since some time. Since v4 is already in effect, it would be better to know the deprecation date for v3, so that switching can be easy.

Comment: What did google tell you as it GA is a google product?

Comment: Google Adwords has a sunset dates page(https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/sunset-dates) for API versions. But I am unable to find similar info for Google Analytics